# Not able to locate an Element using selenium with java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to selenium + java and I'm trying to locate an element (search bar) on the page "https://www.youtube.com/"
When I use the xpath on the browser tools, it highlights the correct element.
When I run the code, I keep getting an exception **" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException"**

The code that I'm using can be found below

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();

try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
}
        
//To click on the cookie pop pup
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@aria-label='Accept the use of cookies and other data for the purposes described']")).click();
        
try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
}

//To send text to the search field
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='ytd-searchbox']")).sendKeys("Selenium");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
//Create an object of selenium's explicit wait
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(30));
        
//Click on Accept All button
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@aria-label='Accept the use of cookies and other data for the purposes described']"))).click();

//Send keys Selenium into search box
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='search']"))).sendKeys("Selenium");
```

Imports required:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import java.time.Duration;
```

Comment: This is working after commenting out code for "Accept All button" and replacing search by id with xpath  -       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='search']"))).sendKeys("Selenium");

Comment: @VasanthSubramanian - Yes you are right. Updated answer and changed locator strategy from `ID` to `XPATH`. There seems to be more than one elements with `id=search`. Hence `ID` locator seems to be not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the correctness of your xpath by going to

`Developer Tools in your browser` -> `Elements` -> `Ctrl + F` -> `Paste your xpath into the search bar`

I`ve tried search on https://www.youtube.com/ by your xpath:

```
//button[@aria-label='Accept the use of cookies and other data for the purposes described']
```

and there were not any matches. So try to edit your xpath.